Having Trouble with Contributor analytics graph on gitLab
I’ve been making commits to a group project using gitLab, we merged my branch to the main, my graph showing my commits to main remained flat, saying I hadn’t made any commits and yet when you check the commits made to my branch it shows that I did commit files on those dates
I’m really a beginner, this is my first time using gitLab, I don’t know what to do
